# Mule 4 Nested XML Schema imports failing in APIKit Router

Tags: xml, mule, mulesoft, apikit

I am trying to put an XML Schema validation on the APIKit Router for validation of request

The schema structure is as follows

```
root.xsd -- (imports) --> notifications.xsd -- (imports) --> objects.xsd
```

All of these xsd files are placed in the same schema folder.

The problem that I am facing is that when I trigger any request to the API, it's unable to import the third schema (Objects.xsd), it gives the following error

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : File Not Found: /home/ion-mule/objects.xsd (No such file or directory)
Element               : demo/processors/0 @ raml-demo:demo.xml:17
Element DSL           : <apikit:router config-ref="demo-config"></apikit:router>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
FlowStack             : at demo-main(demo-main/processors/0 @ demo:demo.xml:17)
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have placed all the files properly in the same folder, but not sure why it is always not able to fetc the third xsd file.

Below is the schema and example payload

root.xsd

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="notifications.xsd" namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" />
  <xsd:element name="Envelope">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Body">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element xmlns:q1="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" ref="q1:notifications" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>`

notifications.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="objects.xsd" namespace="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" />
  <xs:element name="notifications">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SessionId" nillable="true" />
        <xs:element name="Url" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Notification">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="sObject">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" ref="q1:Id" />
                    <xs:element xmlns:q3="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" ref="q2:Name" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

objects.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
</xs:schema>
```

XML Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
   <Url>https://somerandomurl.com</Url>
   <Notification>
    <Id>04l0uioAAM</Id>
    <sObject xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>xyx033fcml98i</sf:Id>
     <sf:Name>7654</sf:Name>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please share your suggestions

Comment: It looks like the schema file is being search in an incorrect directory.
What are the version of the APIKit module, the Mule Runtime version, and the APIKit configuration in XML?

Comment: Yes its searching in the wrong directory, I tried on studio and cloudb, in studio it searches in the bin directory of the tooling server whereas on cloudhub it searches in home/ion/mule.

The api-kit-module version is 1.3.13, Mule runtime is 4.3.0 and the APIKit Configuration is auto generated using the scaffolder.

Comment: It looks like the search is done in the current directory instead of being relative to the previous included file.

Comment: when looking for notification, the first import from root xsd it reads from the correct path
D:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202007101534\mule\apps\raml-demos\api
\schemas\notification.xsd

But when it comes to read the second one the objects.xsd which is imported by notifications.xsd the path changes

D:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202007101534\mule\bin\object.xsd 

for objects.xsd it moves to bin folder after the mule folder.

Comment: I tried degrading the api-kit-router module to 1.3.6 and it worked, but I still can't figure out why with the latest version it fails to read the file.

Comment: It might be a bug.