# Error while using import file in the XSD of RAML design with APIKIt router

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, apikit, anypoint-exchange

Error: `File Not Found: C:\work\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202206241916\mule\bin\data-type\test.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified)` while calling API, APIKit router giving above issue.

I have used two XSD files one is main.xsd and test.xsd.
test.xsd is imported in the main.xsd.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue

Used mule-apikit-module 1.7.1 and Mule runtime 4.4.0.

Comment: Where in the source project are those files located?

Comment: In Raml both files are present in data-type folder and importing the main.xsd file using types in main raml file. In source project those are located in project repository. Can you please help me on this.. I found this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795691/mule-4-nested-xml-schema-imports-failing-in-apikit-router) and tries same way but didn't help.. its a old version right

Comment: @aled Can you please provide solution.

Comment: No, I can not provide a solution until I understand what is the cause of the issue. You said both files are in the `data-type` directory in the project repository. That is not really clear. Do you mean that you are importing those files from Anypoint Exchange?

Comment: When I download specification from the design center and added into api folder in studio , its working fine.. But when I am directly downloading raml asset from exchange to studio and scaffold flows is not working. Yes its an issue with importing form exchange.